# AngularJS, $cookieStore inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to achieve my goal by using $cookieStore inside my custom directive, but it seems to not working.

Simple as,

```
$cookieStore.put('setMe', 123); ( INSIDE DIRECTIVE )
```

Then fetch inside controller

```
$cookieStore.get('setMe'); ( IN CONTROLLER )
```

and that's gave me

```
undefined.
```

Any solutions? Is that possible to set cookie inside of directive and acccess it then in controller?

Comment: Have you looked in the browser to see if the cookie was actually saved?

Answer (score 2):

**Controller**

```
var App = angular.module('App',['ngCookies']);
App.controller('cookieCtrl',function($scope, $cookieStore){
           var name =  $cookieStore.get("Name");
           console.log(name);
});
```

**directive**

```
App.directive('cookie', function ($cookieStore) {

     return{
         restrict:"E",
         template:"<div>  hello </div>",
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                   $cookieStore.put("Name", 'Nishchit');
         }
     }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <html ng-app="App">
  <body ng-controller="cookieCtrl">
        <div>
              <cookie> </cookie>
        </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Note**
Dont forget to include angular-cookies.js  file on html file , this is tested by me and 100% working

Comment: You're wrong, you sets a cookie twice, in controller and in directive. Instead try to save in directive and load in controller, it gaves me undefined after refresh.

Comment: This was not twice , spell mistake put instead of get . now see edited qnswer

Comment: Tested your code and it's working, but whether we bind there click action in directive, so after click cookie is set, then it seems to not working.

Comment: Now see new answer with add cookie on click

Answer (score 2):

This is example with click event .

**Controller**

```
var App = angular.module('App',['ngCookies']);
App.controller('cookieCtrl',function($scope, $cookieStore){

       $scope.addCookie = function(){
              $cookieStore.put("Name", 'Nishchit');
       }

       $scope.getCookie = function(){                
             $scope.cookieName =  $cookieStore.get("Name");
             console.log( $scope.cookieName);
       }
});
```

**directive**

```
App.directive('cookie', function ($cookieStore) {

     return{
         restrict:"E",
         scope:{click:"&"},
         template:"<div ng-click='click()'>  hello </div>",
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                      
         }
     }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <html ng-app="App">
  <body ng-controller="cookieCtrl">
        <div>
              <cookie click="addCookie()"> </cookie>  {{cookieName}}

              <button ng-click="getCookie()">get Cookie </button>
        </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```